# wp_insert_user - how to send verification email before logging in

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, email-verification, wp-create-user

Using below code, I am able to create an user. But when I am login, the user is directly logging in to dashboard and there is no email sent to verify the email address. Is there any way to send verification email once the `wp_insert_user` function is called and the user has to confirm his email address before logging in. I have tried `wp_create_user` and `register_new_user`, but I want the function in the way I have requested.

```
$user_login = wp_slash( $username );
$user_email = wp_slash( $email );
$user_pass = $password;

$userdata = compact('user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass');
$user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
```

Comment: if you use WooCommerce, there is this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-confirmation-email/. another solution is to assign the user to a role like "unvalided" with no capabilities and change the role when the user clicks on the link in the e-mail.

Comment: You can create a meta field with a token and send that tot he user with a URL argument this will be removed once the user clicks the URL. In the login process, you can check the existence or not of that value before allowing the user to continue using the site. Not sure if this will do it for you as i have developed something like this in the past.

Answer (score 4):

**1. Insert user data into wp_users table. Create a page called "Activation" or similar to it and get the ID of that page. An activation email will be sent with the activation link to the user.**

```
function new_user($data) {

    // Separate Data
    $default_newuser = array(
        'user_pass' =>  wp_hash_password( $data['user_pass']),
        'user_login' => $data['user_login'],
        'user_email' => $data['user_email'],
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'role' => 'pending'
    );

    $user_id = wp_insert_user($default_newuser);
    if ( $user_id && !is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
        $code = sha1( $user_id . time() );
        $activation_link = add_query_arg( array( 'key' => $code, 'user' => $user_id ), get_permalink( /* YOUR ACTIVATION PAGE ID HERE */ ));
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'has_to_be_activated', $code, true );
        wp_mail( $data['user_email'], 'ACTIVATION SUBJECT', 'HERE IS YOUR ACTIVATION LINK: ' . $activation_link );
    }
}
```

**2. Check activation status while logging in:**

```
// override core function
if ( !function_exists('wp_authenticate') ) :
function wp_authenticate($username, $password) {
    $username = sanitize_user($username);
    $password = trim($password);

    $user = apply_filters('authenticate', null, $username, $password);

    if ( $user == null ) {
        // TODO what should the error message be? (Or would these even happen?)
        // Only needed if all authentication handlers fail to return anything.
        $user = new WP_Error('authentication_failed', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username or incorrect password.'));
    } elseif ( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'has_to_be_activated', true ) != false ) {
        $user = new WP_Error('activation_failed', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: User is not activated.'));
    }

    $ignore_codes = array('empty_username', 'empty_password');

    if (is_wp_error($user) && !in_array($user->get_error_code(), $ignore_codes) ) {
        do_action('wp_login_failed', $username);
    }

    return $user;
}
endif;
```

**3. Below function will get execute if the user clicks the activation link in the email.**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse8170_activate_user' );
function wpse8170_activate_user() {
    if ( is_page() && get_the_ID() == /* YOUR ACTIVATION PAGE ID HERE */ ) {
        $user_id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'user', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array( 'options' => array( 'min_range' => 1 ) ) );
        if ( $user_id ) {
            // get user meta activation hash field
            $code = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'has_to_be_activated', true );
            if ( $code == filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'key' ) ) {
                delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'has_to_be_activated' );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Very nice. Maybe need to change user role when activation key is verified.

Comment: And at this time, 'pending' role must exists to be removed